# Instances along curve from mesh Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Hi is there a solution to transform rotation of instance from mesh like on screen. Mesh is converted to curve in Geonodes but tangents must be calculated somehow from nearby vertices is there a simple solution for it [image]

To be more specific I've added image. Numbers are indexes and I need to rotate gizmos to look at neighbor indexes
[image]

Comment: tbh i have no idea how you want it to be....and what and how you want it to rotate. So maybe it is a good idea to show us a picture how it should look like. "normally" GN related questions are answered within 1 hour or less...so i think i am not the only one who doesn't understand what you want here.....

Comment: Hi, Chis thanks for interest I've added next image to be more specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the curve tangent with an Align Euler to Vector node to get a rotation pointing to the curve tangent:

[image: Aligning rotation to curve tangent]

Result:

[image: Instances pointing to curve tangent]

Now, if you want some other axis pointing to the surface normal, you can capture the normal before converting the mesh to curve and then use it to align the tangent rotation (using the tangent pointing axis as pivot):

[image: Geometry Nodes align to tangent and normal]

Result:

[image: instances rotation pointing to tangent with Z aligned to normal]

Comment: Thanks, It works